# Zigzag Movement of an object in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want the aliens to move in a zigzag pattern.

Currently they are moving straight down.

The game is currently set sideways.

This is the Alien class

```
class Alien(Sprite):

    def __init__(self,ss_game):
        super().__init__()

        self.screen = ss_game.screen
        self.settings = ss_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ss_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien_2.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.rect.height
        self.rect.y = self.rect.width

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)


    def _check_edges(self):

        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.top >= screen_rect.top or self.rect.bottom <= self.screen_rect.bottom:
            return True


    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += (self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction)
```

These are a few more lines of code which decide/create an amount of aliens and there movement.

```
    def _create_fleet(self):

        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        ship_width, ship_height = self.ship.rect.size
        space_y = self.settings.screen_height +(alien_height) - ship_height
        number_y = space_y // (2*alien_height) 
        space_x = self.settings.screen_width + (alien_width) - 5 * ship_width
        rows = space_x // (2*alien_height)
        for row in range(rows):
            for number in range(number_y):
                self._create_aliens(number, row)

    def _create_aliens(self,number,row):

        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width,alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = alien_width + (1.5*alien_width) * row
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien_width + (2*alien_width) * number
        self.aliens.add(alien) 

    def update_aliens(self):

        self.aliens.update()
        self._check_fleet_edges()

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien._check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.x += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1
```

This a picture of the current game, there is space on the right of alien and on the left of aliens

[image]

The code may be little messy due to changes/experiments,
If there is something that doesn't make sense you can ask me.

Currently the aliens move in a linear motion, and are fast(side note).

I want the aliens to move in a zigzag motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean by "zigzag" to mean sort of like a sawtooth motion (moving up and down repeatedly while moving to one side constantly), each alien would trace a path like this (ending at the `.`):

```
/\  /\  /\  /\  .
  \/  \/  \/  \/
```

If that's the case, aliens need to update their `y` axis in addition to their `x` axis.

On the other hand, if you want the y-coordinate to stay constant and move left, then right, then left etc. along the x-axis, then it's not clear from the code you shared how that would happen.

It seems like the way you've written it, as soon as a single alien exceeds the screen space, the entire fleet changes direction. This may be desired, but you could potentially simplify your code by doing this check and direction change on a per-alien basis.

For example, instead of changing `fleet_direction` you could add a `direction` parameter to the Alien class, and change the direction of each alien individually.

This would allow you to write your update_aliens function like this:

```py
for alien in aliens:
  if alien.check_edges():
    alien.direction *= -1
  alien.update()
```

[edit]

Based on your comments, you could try adding some additional y-update to your `Alien.update` function like this:

```py
def __init__(self):
  #...
  self.y_direction = 1
  self.y_counter = 1


def update(self):
  self.rect.x += #...
  self.rect.y += 1
  if self.y_counter == 10: # zig size is 10
    self.y_counter = 0
    self.y_direction *= -1 # change y direction only
  self.y_counter += 1
```

This is similar to the sine suggestion from another answer, but you should keep your bounds checking, so your aliens reverse direction when they hit the edge of the screen.

Alternatively, you could apply the direction change *only* when the sprite touches the edge of the screen:

```py
class Alien(Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    # ...
    self.x_direction = 1
    self.y_direction = 1

  def _check_edges(self):
    # ...
    if self.rect.y > screen_rect.top or self.rect.y < screen_rect.botttom:
      self.y_direction *= -1
    if self.rect.x > screen_rect.right or self.rect.x < screen_rect.left:
      self.x_direction *= -1

  def update(self):
    # ...
    self.rect.x += self.settings.alien_speed * self.x_direction
    self.rect.y += self.settings.alien_speed * self.y_direction
```

Comment: Hello  Sir, firstly I want the alien to move to the right/left after that I have set a condition that if an alien is at the right or left corner of the screen , the aliens should move down , it true that my code isn't perfectly written because I don't know how to do so  but I have tried(i am only able to either move left/right or up or down).  @Alex Shroyer

Comment: In that case the other answer here has a suggestion for updating both x and y in a sine-wave shape, maybe that is what you want.

Comment: I saw that, but the aliens are moving out of the screen.

Comment: @ Alex Shroyer I have used the alternative code,  Is this accurate: "   def update_aliens(self):

        self.aliens.update()
        self._check_fleet_edges()

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien._check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_xdirection()
                break

    def _change_fleet_xdirection(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.x += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.x_direction *= -1         
"

Comment: I'm not totally sure, as the formatting makes it harder to follow. Assuming `fleet_direction` applies to the entire "fleet", be sure you only call `_change_fleet_xdirection` one time for the fleet as a whole, rather than once per alien. Otherwise, if you call this an even number of times, the fleet direction will end up the same as it started.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will probably fix my code tomorrow!@Alex Shroyer

Answer (score 2):

You can make them move along a sin wave. In you case it would probably look this this:

```
class Alien(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,ss_game):
        #...
        self.frequency = 2
        self.ySpeed = 0.01
        self.overallY = self.rect.y
        self.amplitude = 30

 def update(self):
        t = pygame.time.get_ticks() * self.ySpeed % 500
        self.rect.x += (self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction * self.frequency)
        self.rect.y = (self.amplitude * math.sin(t)) + self.overallY
```

Here is a self-contained example.

```
import pygame
import math

ySpeed = 0.01
xVel = 0.1
x = 0
y = 250

amplitude = 20
frequency = 2

window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.init()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    #stuff to do with x direction
    x += xVel * frequency
    if (x < 0 or x > 600 - 30):
         xVel *= -1

    #generate the zigzag y
    t = pygame.time.get_ticks() * ySpeed % 500
    zigzagY = (amplitude * math.sin( t )) + y

    #draw
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (x, zigzagY, 30, 30))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Your entire updated code:

```
import pygame
import math
from pygame.locals import *

class Settings:
    def __init__(self):

        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed = 1.5

        self.bullet_speed = 1.5
        self.bullet_width = 15
        self.bullet_height = 3
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullet_allowed = 3

        self.alien_speed = 1
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        self.fleet_direction = 1

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen

        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship_2.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midright = self.screen_rect.midright

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_down and self.y < 750:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_up and self.y > 0:
            self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,ai_game):
        super().__init__()

        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color 

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0, self.settings.bullet_width, self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midright = ai_game.ship.rect.midright
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def update(self):
        self.x -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)


class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien_2.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.y = self.rect.width
        self.rect.x = self.rect.height

        # Store the alien's exact horizontal position.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.frequency = 1
        self.ySpeed = 0.09
        self.overallY = self.rect.y
        self.amplitude = 4

    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.top <= screen_rect.top or self.rect.bottom >= 800:
            return True

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += (self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction * self.frequency)

        #you can either comment out the one bellow and use the next two lines
        #or you can leave it as it is.
        #You might also want to change the frequency, ySpeed, amplitude and
        #self.settings.alien_speed values to get it to zigzag exactly how you
        #want it.
        
        self.rect.y = self.overallY + (self.amplitude * math.sin(self.ySpeed * self.rect.x))

##        t = pygame.time.get_ticks() * self.ySpeed % 500
##        self.rect.y = (self.amplitude * math.sin(t)) + self.overallY

class SideShooter:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_aliens()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Respond to key releases."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullet_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        self.bullets.update()

        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.right <= self.screen.get_rect().left:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
        self._check_bullet_detection()         

    def _check_bullet_detection(self):
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)   

        if not self.aliens:
            self.bullets.empty()
            self._create_fleet()


    def _update_aliens(self):
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2* alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (3*alien_width)
        

        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -
                                (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)
        
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)

    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.overallY = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        #alien.rect.y = alien.y
        #self.overallY = alien.y
        alien.rect.x = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break
            
    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.x += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

ss = SideShooter()
ss.run_game()
```

Comment: Hello Sir/Ma'am , I got what was intended but the alien are moving out of the screen . Is there a way to fix that? @user16038533

Comment: @help In the y-direction? It shouldn't in x - I don't think. Try lowering the amplitude

Comment: I think I didn't  understand properly , what you said , I implemented your line  "     self.frequency = 2
        self.ySpeed = 0.01
        self.zigzagY = 0
        self.amplitude = 30

 def update(self):
        t = pygame.time.get_ticks() * self.ySpeed % 500
        self.rect.x += (self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction * self.frequency)
        self.zigzagY = (self.amplitude * math.sin(t)) + self.rect.y"

Comment: But couldn't understand how to change  self.rect.y with self.zigzagY / plus I changed the amplitude all the aliens got cramped at the top right corner of screen @ user16038533

Comment: @help Can you show me your code that draws the aliens please. You can edit your question and post it there

Comment: I have already shown the basic working  of creating the aliens in the second code, if you are talking about how I drew it , it was  "self.aliens.draw(self.screen)", the window size is 1200 by 800  and the alien size is 60*58. I have never used the math library so it hard for me understand    
 @ user16038533

Comment: @help Sorry, I didn't notice your class inherited from sprite. I have edited the answer. See if that works

Comment: I didn't notice that but I had already used Alien(Sprite) so the answer would be no.

Comment: @help No. that's not what I changed. It now directly updates `self.y` instead of `self.gigzagY`

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I got the solution, The game is now working as intended.

Comment: I tried your new code, the aliens are not moving out of the screen now but only one row is appearing, if you could help me , I have posted my entire code as an answer , I changed Alien.update .

Comment: @help I have updated the answer and posted your entire code with required changes. It should work now. The problem was that `self.overallY` was not being updated in the `_create_alien` function.

Comment: thank you so much ! I really like your example code.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work as intended:

import sys
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Settings:

```
def __init__(self):

    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    self.ship_speed = 1.5

    self.bullet_speed = 1.5
    self.bullet_width = 15
    self.bullet_height = 3
    self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
    self.bullet_allowed = 3

    self.alien_speed = 1
    self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
    self.fleet_direction = 1
```

class Ship:

```
def __init__(self, ai_game):
    self.screen = ai_game.screen

    self.settings = ai_game.settings

    self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship_2.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.rect.midright = self.screen_rect.midright

    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    self.moving_up = False
    self.moving_down = False

def update(self):
    if self.moving_down and self.y < 750:
        self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
    if self.moving_up and self.y > 0:
        self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
    self.rect.y = self.y     
def blitme(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

class Bullet(Sprite):

```
def __init__(self,ai_game):
    super().__init__()

    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.settings = ai_game.settings
    self.color = self.settings.bullet_color 

    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0, self.settings.bullet_width, self.settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.midright = ai_game.ship.rect.midright
    self.x = float(self.rect.x)

def update(self):
    self.x -= self.settings.bullet_speed
    self.rect.x = self.x

def draw_bullet(self):
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

class Alien(Sprite):

```
def __init__(self, ai_game):
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.settings = ai_game.settings

    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien_2.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
    self.rect.y = self.rect.width
    self.rect.x = self.rect.height

    # Store the alien's exact horizontal position.
    self.y = float(self.rect.x)

def check_edges(self):
    screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
    if self.rect.top <= screen_rect.top or self.rect.bottom >= 800:
        return True

def update(self):
    self.y += (self.settings.alien_speed *
                    self.settings.fleet_direction)
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

class SideShooter:

```
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    self.settings = Settings()

    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,self.settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    self.ship = Ship(self)
    self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

    self._create_fleet()

def run_game(self):
    """Start the main loop for the game."""
    while True:
        self._check_events()
        self.ship.update()
        self._update_bullets()
        self._update_aliens()
        self._update_screen()

def _check_events(self):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            self._check_keydown_events(event)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            self._check_keyup_events(event)

def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        self.ship.moving_up = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        self.ship.moving_down = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        self._fire_bullet()

def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        self.ship.moving_up = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        self.ship.moving_down = False

def _fire_bullet(self):
    if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullet_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

def _update_bullets(self):
    self.bullets.update()

    for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.right <= self.screen.get_rect().left:
            self.bullets.remove(bullet)
    self._check_bullet_detection()         

def _check_bullet_detection(self):
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)   

    if not self.aliens:
        self.bullets.empty()
        self._create_fleet()


def _update_aliens(self):
    self._check_fleet_edges()
    self.aliens.update()

def _create_fleet(self):

    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2* alien_width)
    number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (3*alien_width)
    

    ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
    available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -
                            (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)
    
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)

def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    alien.y = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.y = alien.y
    alien.rect.x = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    self.aliens.add(alien)

def _check_fleet_edges(self):
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            self._change_fleet_direction()
            break
        
def _change_fleet_direction(self):
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.x += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
    self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

def _update_screen(self):
    self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
    self.ship.blitme()
    for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
ss = SideShooter()

ss.run_game()
```